# To use variables from a python file without running it again and again

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, variables, python-import

I have 3 python files (Parameter.py,main.py and main(1).py).
A huge numpy array is being created in the first .py file. It takes lot of time to make that array.
The other two python files use that array in further computation.

I am using

```
from Parameters import *
```

in the main.py and main(1).py.

It runs the Parameter.py again and again.

Is there any way, if I can run Parameter.py only one time and the array which is being created there can be used by other two files all the time?

Comment: Use `numpy.save()` and `numpy.load()` to store the array in a data file, instead of re-running the code that generates the array.

Comment: The array is large and 3 dimensional. Saving it to csv shows an error because it saves only 2-d data.

Comment: I feel there should be some way to pass a variable from one file to another by just running the first file once.

Comment: `numpy.save()` saves it in a binary format, not CSV.

Comment: All variables go away when a script exits.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html :  numpy.savez_compressed(file, *args, **kwds) : Save several arrays into a single file in compressed .npz format.

Comment: in your main.py you should try to load a config file containing the array and you would run Parameters.py that saves the array in a config file only if this file does not exist, this way your parameters will run only once

Comment: The best way to share global variables across modules across a single program is to create a config module. Just import the config module in all modules of your application; the module then becomes available as a global name.